# How to create conditional group tags with nested data in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

**My data looks like this:**
[image]

I have 5 different levels with nested data:

- Categories (e.g., "Countries")
- Countries (e.g., "USA")
- Cities (e.g., "New York")
- Counties (e.g., "Manhattan")
- Places (e.g., "Times Square")

Each row in my df (except for LVL 1 entries) is linked to a parent (a level above). For example: Times Square -> Manhatten -> New York -> USA -> Countries

For each `Name`, there is a corresponding `n_values` column, indicating the number of data entries.

**My goal: I want to form groups with >=8 data entries**. For groups with `n_values <8`, I want to merge them with the `Parent` column a level above. This new allocation should be expressed in a new variable `new_group`.

It is important to start in the lower levels first! For example, there are only 2 data entries for "Times Square" so we want to merge those entries with the parent "Manhattan". Manhattan now has 3+2=5 data entries. This is still <8 so we merge those 5 entries with the next parent "New York" which now hast 16+5=21 entries, so we're good.

I have tried to write a loop like this:

```
for (i in 5:1){
df %>% filter(Level==i) %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(n = n())
```

However, I fail to merge that information with the original data to create the dataset I want. Can anyone help?

The data:

```
structure(list(ID = c(19,12,3,41,50,6,77,83,9,105,11),
                     Parent = c(NA,19,12,3,41,12,19,77,77,19,105),
                     Level = c(1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,3,2,3),
                     Name = c("Countries","USA","New York","Manhattan","Times Square",
                              "Boston","UK","London","Oxford","Canada","Vancouver"),
                     n_values = c(NA,17,16,3,2,13,12,7,8,9,8)),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: Maybe it is simple but I do not understand! Could you please try to clarify with an expected output?

Comment: Hey @TarJae, you can find an expected output in jdobres answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your data is stored in a data frame called `df`. The most straightforward approach would be to first sort the rows of the table by "Level" in descending order and set "new_group" to the values of "Name". We'll also track the per-group totals in a column called "new_values". Then iterate through the rows until a row with `new_values < 8` is encountered, at which point that row's "new_group" is changed to that of its parent, and its "Parent" is also updated to match its parent's "Parent". At that point, the row loop restarts. The outer loop terminates when no "new_group"s have `new_values < 8`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_sorted <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Level)) %>% 
  mutate(new_group = Name) %>% 
  group_by(new_group) %>% 
  mutate(new_values = sum(n_values)) %>% 
  ungroup

while (any(df_sorted$new_values < 8, na.rm = T)) {
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(df_sorted)) {
    
    if (df_sorted$new_values[i] < 8) {
      
      to_id <- df_sorted$Parent[i]
      to_row <- which(df_sorted$ID == to_id)
      
      df_sorted$new_group[i] <- df_sorted$Name[to_row]
      df_sorted$Parent[i] <- df_sorted$Parent[to_row]

      df_sorted <- df_sorted %>% 
        group_by(new_group) %>% 
        mutate(new_values = sum(n_values)) %>% 
        ungroup
      
      break # terminate the for loop immediately and return to the outer while loop
    }
  }
}

      ID Parent Level Name         n_values new_group new_values
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
 1    50     12     5 Times Square        2 New York          21
 2    41     12     4 Manhattan           3 New York          21
 3     3     12     3 New York           16 New York          21
 4     6     12     3 Boston             13 Boston            13
 5    83     19     3 London              7 UK                19
 6     9     77     3 Oxford              8 Oxford             8
 7    11    105     3 Vancouver           8 Vancouver          8
 8    12     19     2 USA                17 USA               17
 9    77     19     2 UK                 12 UK                19
10   105     19     2 Canada              9 Canada             9
11    19     NA     1 Countries          NA Countries         NA
```

**Edit:** The version below adds a "touched" column to track rows that have been modified in the loop, and also adds some checks for `NA` values. For the data set used above, it produces an identical result to the previous version. It also appears to work correctly on the data set below.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(19,12,3,41,50,6,77,83,9,105,11), Parent = c(NA,19,12,3,41,12,19,77,77,19,105), Level = c(1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,3,2,3), Name = c("Countries","USA","New York","Manhattan","Times Square", "Boston","UK","London","Oxford","Canada","Vancouver"), n_values = c(NA,0,0,3,2,0,12,7,8,9,8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

df_sorted <- df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Level)) %>% 
  mutate(new_group = Name) %>% 
  group_by(new_group) %>% 
  mutate(
    new_values = sum(n_values), 
    touched = is.na(n_values) | n_values >= 8
  ) %>% 
  ungroup

while (any(!df_sorted$touched)) {
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(df_sorted)) {
    
    if (df_sorted$new_values[i] < 8 & !is.na(df_sorted$Parent[i]) & any(!df_sorted$touched)) {
      
      to_id <- df_sorted$Parent[i]
      to_row <- which(df_sorted$ID == to_id)
      
      df_sorted$new_group[i] <- df_sorted$Name[to_row]
      df_sorted$Parent[i] <- df_sorted$Parent[to_row]
      df_sorted$touched[i] <- TRUE
      
      df_sorted <- df_sorted %>% 
        group_by(new_group) %>% 
        mutate(new_values = sum(n_values, na.rm = T)) %>% 
        ungroup
      
      break # terminate the for loop immediately and return to the outer while loop
    }
  }
}

      ID Parent Level Name         n_values new_group new_values touched
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <lgl>  
 1    50     NA     5 Times Square        2 Countries          5 TRUE   
 2    41     NA     4 Manhattan           3 Countries          5 TRUE   
 3     3     NA     3 New York            0 Countries          5 TRUE   
 4     6     NA     3 Boston              0 Countries          5 TRUE   
 5    83     19     3 London              7 UK                19 TRUE   
 6     9     77     3 Oxford              8 Oxford             8 TRUE   
 7    11    105     3 Vancouver           8 Vancouver          8 TRUE   
 8    12     NA     2 USA                 0 Countries          5 TRUE   
 9    77     19     2 UK                 12 UK                19 TRUE   
10   105     19     2 Canada              9 Canada             9 TRUE   
11    19     NA     1 Countries          NA Countries          5 TRUE
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! I have one question: when using your code for my actual dataset (it's just way longer), I get: error in df_sorted$new_group[i] <- df_sorted$Bezeichnung[to_row] : 
  Replacement has length 0.

I assume some groups stay <8 even after aggregating with higher-level units? Can you help me avoiding the error?

Comment: Please post a data set that reproduces the error.

Comment: structure(list(ID = c(19,12,3,41,50,6,77,83,9,105,11),
               Parent = c(NA,19,12,3,41,12,19,77,77,19,105),
               Level = c(1,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,3,2,3),
               Name = c("Countries","USA","New York","Manhattan","Times Square",
                        "Boston","UK","London","Oxford","Canada","Vancouver"),
               n_values = c(NA,0,0,3,2,0,12,7,8,9,8)),
          class = "data.frame",
          row.names = c(NA, -11L))

Comment: I got a slightly different error message with this reporeducable data set, however, I think the same error occurs: the loop reached the highest level but new_values[i] is still <8

Comment: I've made some edits (see new section) that add better handling for NA values.

Comment: the loop has been running for over 20 minutes now (911 rows). Do you have an idea why that is?

Comment: Sounds like it might be stuck in an infinite loop. The loop won't complete until all of the values in `df_sorted$touched == TRUE`, so if something is preventing the loop from reaching the later rows, that could be the cause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243832/discussion-between-diggi2395-and-jdobres).